# Good resources for traditional testers adapting to an Agile environment

Tags: agile-testing, development-process, waterfall

I haven't experienced a transition from waterfall to Agile myself - I worked for companies using Prince2, waterfall approaches to managing projects, and then I got a job working for a company using Agile. But for most traditional testers, their first exposure to Agile will be when their company decides to adopt it.

What resources are there for testers in a company transitioning to using an Agile approach? What problems do they tend to face, and how do they overcome those problems?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the most common problems that I've faced is the role of the tester.  Often times, teams/companies start to believe that an agile approach using TDD eliminates the need for testing.  My first experience with it was when of my former teams was told that they were going to become an agile team.  [Agile Testing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321534468) by Lisa Crispin and Janet Gregory helped me out immensely.
  It seems as though it's been so long since I've worked on a traditional waterfall team that I've forgotten some of the challenges that I faced.  As I say (perhaps too often), communications and a willingness to adapt just as the rest of the team is adapting is key.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Agile Testing, by Gregory and Crispin]
<sub>(source: [images-amazon.com](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51oB%2BtnQwxL._SL500_AA300_.jpg))</sub>

[Agile Testing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321534468)

This is the (IMO) canonical book I refer people to in this situation. It's a fun book to read, and gives you plenty of ideas and context to start with as you transition.

Answer (score 0):

Learn what Agile is first, everything else will fall into place. 
I managed a test team as part of a larger Agile team, I read the "Agile Testing" books much later and found them similar to what we already did using intuition and simple common sense.

Comment: I don't think I'd agree - I've come across various resources intended for Agile teams that are just totally unhelpful to testers seeking to find useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Good Reads

http://www.scribd.com/doc/45836192/Agile-Testing-Techniques-Slides-Agile-Atlanta-12-2010

http://blog.scrumpad.com/2008/11/7-practices-to-agile-qa.html

Please check.